# Getch and getche not found in Xcode

Tags: c, xcode

I'm learning programming C language, but I faced a problem.I couldn't use the function getch and getche in Xcode. I included the header and  in my project, but it said getch and getche are undefined symbol. How could I solve it? Thank you.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cp5oL.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getch` and `getche` are functions from old Turbo C compiler from Borland. You won't be able to find it in XCode. Instead you should use `getchar,` combined with other functions you can emulate the same functionality.

Comment: How could I combined with other functions by using gerchar? thank you

Comment: https://www.includehelp.com/c-programs/gotoxy-clrscr-getch-getche-for-gcc-linux.aspx shows examples for Linux and should work for XCode as Mac OS X is based on BSD.